# Rancher Desktop hangs

Tags: windows, kubernetes, rancher, rancher-desktop

I've just installed Rancher Desktop on a Windows 10 laptop, but this hangs in "Waiting for nodes".
All the logs file are empty even when the debug is enabled and the Images tab stays in "Waiting for image manager to be ready".
What can I do?

The machine has an i5-7200U CPU with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I occasionally face this issue unfortunately, so far my solution was waiting long enough so it'll resolve on its own.